# Cantor's proof that every bounded monotone sequence of real numbers converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Cantor constructed the field of real numbers by using Cauchy sequences.
According to him every Cauchy sequence of real numbers converges (correct me if I'm wrong).
So how did he prove that every bounded monotone sequence of real numbers converges by using this property?

Comment: Using the [least upper bound property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property) of the real numbers. See also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566635/show-that-every-monotonous-increasing-and-bounded-sequence-is-cauchy?rq=1) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744670/if-a-sequence-converges-then-it-is-cauchy?rq=1) question.

Comment: Presumably by showing that a bounded and monotone sequence must necessarily be Cauchy.

Comment: @Winther How did he prove the least upper bound property?

Comment: The least upper bound property is an *axiom* of the real numbers (see the last paragraph [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Real_Analysis/The_real_numbers#The_axioms)).

Comment: @Winther You misunderstand my question. I'm asking how he proved it by using his construction.

Comment: I don't know exactly how Cantor did it, but I know the 'standard' modern way of doing it. Is this what you are after or do you specifically want Cantor's proof?

Comment: So what is the standard way?

Comment: Here is a rough outline of the proof that an increasing bounded sequence converges: $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded so by the least upper bound property it has a least upper bound $a$ and by def. $a_n\leq a$ for all $n$. For any $\epsilon>0$ we can therefore find $N$ s.t. for $n>N$ then $a\geq a_n > a-\epsilon$ (otherwise this contradicts $a$ being a least upper bound / that $a_n$ is increasing). Thus $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$ for $n>N$ which is the definition that the sequence converges to $a$. If you want to show that $a_n$ is Cauchy then the same type of argument can be used.

Comment: @Winther How do you prove the least upper bound property using the fact that every Cauchy sequence converges?

Comment: You cannot prove the least upper bound property (also known as the completeness axiom) since this is an axiom. However, it is possible to take "every Cauchy sequence converges" as an axiom instead and then deduce the LUB property. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746409/how-can-i-show-the-statement-every-cauchy-sequence-converges-can-replace-the) for how to do this.

Comment: @Winther If I'm not mistaken, OP wants to construct the real numbers as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences with terms in $\mathbb{Q}$, with $(a_n) \sim (b_n)$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n - b_n = 0$.  He then wants to prove the monotone convergence theorem with this definition of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you are really asking how Cantor did it, then the question belongs in http://hsm.stackexchange.com I think.

Comment: @SpamIAm You might be right. The only thing I'm sure of is that I have probably just added to the confusion above rather than helping to clear it up:)

Comment: @Winther: Of course we can prove axioms, you can prove the axiom of choice from Zorn's lemma, and you can prove the axiom of induction from the well-ordering principle.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That is just replacing one axiom with another in the sense that the proof needs to assume something new. I tried to point this out two comments above in the case of the completeness axiom vs convergence of cauchy sequences.

Comment: @Winther: And here you want to prove that the Cauchy completion of the rationals, has the least upper bound property. The fact something *can* be taken as an axiom does not mean that it cannot be proved from other definitions (which is a fancy name for axioms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take as given that every Cauchy sequence of real numbers converges. Suppose $a_n$ is a sequence of real numbers which is monotone and not convergent. Since it is not convergent, it is not Cauchy, so

$$(\exists \varepsilon > 0)(\forall N \in \mathbb{N})(\exists m,n \in \mathbb{N}) \: m>n\geq N \text{ and }  |a_m - a_n| > \varepsilon.$$

Fix such a $\varepsilon$, then use this statement inductively to get a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ with $|a_{n_{k+1}} - a_{n_k}|>\varepsilon$ for every $k$. To see how to do this, start with $N=1$, get $m,n$ and call them $n_1$ and $n_0$. Now use $N=n_0$, get $m,n$, one will be the same $n_1$ and you will also get an $n_2$. Repeat this procedure.

Now by the monotonicity, $a_{n_{k+1}} > a_{n_k} + \varepsilon$ and so $a_{n_k} > a_{n_0} + k \varepsilon$. Hence $a_{n_k}$ is not bounded so $a_n$ is not bounded either. We have shown that if a sequence of real numbers is monotone and not convergent then it is not bounded. The desired statement follows by contraposition.

Comment: I don't think this answer's the OP's question.  If I'm not mistaken, OP wants to construct the real numbers as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences with terms in $\mathbb{Q}$, with $(a_n) \sim (b_n)$ iff $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n - b_n = 0$.

Comment: @SpamIAm "How did he prove that every bounded monotone sequence of real numbers converges using [the property that every Cauchy sequence of real numbers converges]?" is how I read the last sentence of the OP. I don't think the OP wants to prove this initial step.

Comment: Oh okay, maybe you're right.  His comment above: "You misunderstand my question. I'm asking how he proved it by using his construction"  made me think otherwise.